# Functional and UI Test cases for a Slider

Tags: automated-testing, webdriver, selenium2, functional

I am working on a website. Here is the URL : http://northeastindiaholidays.com/.

There are two sliders on the front page:

1. The one with in the background, with a full resolution image.
2. The second one which slides the name of the background image.

I was thinking about the possible functional and UI test scenarios for the slider only.

I don't know if it is possible or even useful to design.

But if we design any such test cases, what would they be.

I mean a few examples here.

And can we use Selenium webdriver to execute those tests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 5 seconds of googling found [Slider movement possible in Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12122824/slider-movement-possible-in-selenium) which is itself a duplicate ... And question was even upvoted...

Comment: Well Peter, I had looked into this one before coming here. But I am not sure if this applies to the slider I am referring to. Since I am new to Selenium, I may be off on this one.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that slider content can be changed manually, the following solution can be used:

```
WebElement slider = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='slider']/a"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
action.click(slider).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT).perform();
```

And then check that text or image has changed.